# Css position differences chrome/safari/firefox

Tags: css, cross-browser, css-position

Its about the footer part of: http://eloboosterz.com/test.php
In Firefox it looks like its supposed to be.
In Chrome the footer is misplaced and finally in Safari total damage.
What is causing the differences?

Comment: I see no difference using Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Here's a link to my site, fix it. Really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your css for #yline_bglow_right to:

```
-moz-transform: rotate(-21deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-21deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-21deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-21deg);
transform: rotate(-21deg);
```

and for #yline_bglow_left to:

```
-moz-transform: rotate(21deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(21deg);
-o-transform: rotate(21deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(21deg);
transform: rotate(21deg);
```

Comment: ty.. but i mean i want the footer fixed ( thats why i have a div around my footer with pos:fixed). For the header it works ( fixed vertical, horizontal margin auto) but for footer not

Comment: use bottom property instead top for your footer

Comment: oh man so easy.. thanks :) can i ask u why the lines are not yellow in safari)

Comment: so please mark as correct answer. Which lines?

Comment: kk done, i mean for example div yline:  -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px -0.5px 1px 1px #888;
   
  box-shadow: inset -1px -0.5px 1px 0.3px #888 ;

   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px -0.5px 1px 1px #888; makes the yellow lines grey in safari

Comment: probably because you set height: 2.5px; change to height: 3px; should work but I doesn't have safari so I can't check to by sure. 
ps. you can't use a half px

Comment: youre right half px was the prob :)